# videoJS: how to add Custom button to the controlBar in the responsive mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js, video.js

I have created a player with videoJS. And I have added buttons to the controlBar. The button is working nice. But when I inspect the page(mobile/ tab) the buttons are not clickable just when I force them.

```
let myButton = player?.controlBar.addChild('button');
myButton.controlText('Paramétres (o)');
player?.controlBar
    .el()
    .insertBefore(myButton.el(), player?.controlBar.getChild('fullscreenToggle').el());
let buttonDom = myButton.el();
buttonDom.innerHTML = SVG.SETTING_SVG;
buttonDom.onclick = function () {
    dispatch();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [clickHandler option](https://videojs.com/guides/components/#adding-a-component). It will be triggered on both clicks and touches.

```js
let myButton = player?.controlBar.addChild('button', {
  clickHandler: function () {
    dispatch();
  }
});
```